# Relational Database Design - Courses offered by universities

Tags: mysql, database

I am creating a database for universities in my country. Particular database of name of the courses offered by each university.

I think I must consider the following points to create a database

1. Possible names of courses, let's assume 100 courses.
2. Name of courses offered by one university, let's assume 60.
3. Number of courses offered by university may differ from one university to another. One may offer 60 courses and other may offer just 50. Courses may overlap.

How do I create a relational database between table of point no.1 and table of point no.2, considering the point no.3. Please suggest a design pattern for this.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would have a table listing all the available courses (in all universities) and another table including the university and the course (one record for each combination) using the ID of the course from the first table. This, of course, is just a very basic description. You may also wish to have a table for universities, course **instances** (meaning, the same course may run several times during the year, even overlapping within the same university to cope with high number of students), etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could have:

- `university_course`, which is a type of course at a `university`
- a `course_category` that broadly collects each type of course together
- Many `course` rows, which give the names of a course within a category.

So:

- `university_course.university_id -> university.id` (a university has many university courses)
- `university_course.category_id -> category.id` (a university course has one category)
- `course.category_id -> category.id` (a category has many courses)

Thus, the set of courses (Computer Science, Networking, Computer Studies, Computer Hardware) can map to a category (Computer Science) and then each university course points to the category.

Comment: This is all what i need. Thank you very much. Wish i could upvote but can't hehe.

Comment: No worries @ujjwalmainali, pleased to help. Bear in mind that you won't always get answers if you do not show what you have tried, so for your next question, please do put down an attempt, even if it is incomplete or not working.